# How to create an effect higher up in the view than the logic that determines it?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, loops, conditional-statements

I have a simple if statement in my view that returns x = 0 or 1. Based on this simple result, I want to change the styling of the div that contains the entire section.

```
<div>
  conditional that returns x=1 vs x=0 (and a few displayed items)
  based on this loop, restyle the div
</div>
```

Let's say, if x = 1, I want to make background-color:rgb(210,215,220);

How can I accomplish this? I am not experienced with Javascript but I'm sure any code required would be very simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to your DIV like:

```
<div ID="colorThis">
  conditional that returns x=1 vs x=0 (and a few displayed items)
  based on this loop, restyle the div
</div>
```

Then do this:

```
if(x==1)
{
  ​document.getElement​ById('colorThis').style.background = 'rgb(210,215,220)'​​​​;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
if(x==1)
{
$("#divid").css("background-color","rgb(210,215,220)");
}
</script>
```

Include jQuery, and give the div's id to `divid`